# Set maximum number of lines for UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to do some special alignment with a UILabel.

I want it to have 1 to 3 lines, whatever content it has.

Currently I'm doing it something like this:

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

label.frame = CGRectMake(114.0f, 88.0f, 187.0f, 0.0f);
[label sizeToFit];
```

which works great if the text is not too long. if the string is something like `@"Hello World"` the UILabel is only 14 points high, if it is some way longer it expands.

Now I want that the text should add it's default `...` triple dots if the text gets too long for three lines, but with the setting on top it expands to the fourth line.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
label.numberOfLines = 3;
CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(SOME_WIDTH,
                                                  3 * label.font.lineHeight)
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
label.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                          size.width,
                          size.height);
```

Comment: works as expected. changed the bounds to frame and changed the line brake mode. 

made a category out of it, check out: https://github.com/martinjuhasz/UILabel-maximumNumberOfLines

Comment: `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` has been deprecated. Use `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` instead. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsparagraphstyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: hi @debleek63 please how can I do it with swift 4

Answer (score 23):

Just set `label.numberOfLines = 3;`.

It is somewhat mislabeled, as it actually holds the maximum amount of lines to display.

Comment: if numberOfLines is not zero, then sizeToFit will not work and i need the sizeToFit behavior, because it should not always be three lines high if it doesn't need to be.

Comment: I misunderstood your question then, sorry

Comment: In my tests, sizeToFit does work just fine when numberOfLines=3.  This could be because in my app, I'm creating a new label each time the text changes, so it doesn't have to shrink it down.  But in that case, it certainly does work to expand the label only as much as needed to fit the text (up to three lines).

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would give it a try:

```
func heightForStringDrawing(myString: String, myFont:UIFont, myWidth:CGFloat) -> (CGFloat, Int) {
    var tc = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: myWidth, height:CGFloat(FLT_MAX)))
    var ts = NSTextStorage(string: myString)
    var lm = NSLayoutManager()
    lm.addTextContainer(tc)
    ts.addLayoutManager(lm)
    ts.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: myFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, ts.length))
    tc.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    lm.glyphRangeForTextContainer(tc)
    let height = lm.usedRectForTextContainer(tc).height
    let lines = Int(Float(height / myFont.lineHeight))
    return (height, lines)
}
```

Comments are certainly welcome!  I adopted this from:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html

Comment: Oh... and I realise that this may not answer his question _specifically_, but It could be useful to whomever comes across it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me (using autolayout):

```
    label.numberOfLines = 0

    // max height for 3 lines, this value worked for me
    // you can try a slightly larger value if needed
    let heightLimit = label.font.lineHeight * 3 + 0.5

    label.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: heightLimit).isActive = true
```

The idea is to limit the height with a `lessThanOrEqual` relation. If the text is small enough, then the height will be defined by label's `sizeToFit` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The "Lines" setting in Interface Builder controls the maximum number of lines.

Check the tooltip of the Lines option in Xcode's Interface Builder:

> Number Of Lines - UILabel `numberOfLines`
>
> The maximum number of lines to use for rendering text.

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

Call `getStringSize`. It will return a variable of type `StringSize` and decide dynamically number of lines.

```
struct StringSize {

    int numberOfLine;
    float height;
    float width;

};

typedef struct StringSize StringSize;



+(StringSize)getStringSize:(NSString *)string ofWidth:(float)width  FontSize:(id)font {

    StringSize sizeForString;

    if(string){
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, 400.0f);
        CGSize appStringSize = [string sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:size     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
        CGSize sizeString = [string sizeWithFont:font];    

        sizeForString.width = appStringSize.width;
        sizeForString.height = appStringSize.height;
        sizeForString.numberOfLine = (int)(sizeForString.height/sizeString.height);
    }else {
        sizeForString.width = 0;
        sizeForString.height = 0;
        sizeForString.numberOfLine = 0;
    }

    return sizeForString;
}
```